# Android App failing again and again to start

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-manifest

I am a beginner in Android.

I am trying to create a sample app which will open facebook inside it.

Now i want to add a back button in it, so that if from every activity it can return to its parent activity page. Otherwise just pressing android back button just throws me out of the app.

**Basic app was working fine but once I added this back button feature, it fails to start.**

MY code is as follows:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.x.nk.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/TDHWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.x.nk;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.TDHWebView);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl(url);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.x.nk">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyWebViewClient.java:

```
package com.x.nk;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Can someone please help where am I going wrong OR How can I do this task?**

Comment: post your style.xml file.

Comment: Just saying, can you check the app permissions once?

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of -

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

I have tested and it's working now.

The `getActionBar()` is returning `null` as your activity is using `SupportActionBar`. In next line, you are calling `setButtonsEnabled()` on a null reference which is causing `NullPointerException` and a crash.

You can achieve the back functionality by finishing your current activity as -

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Also, if you want to use default Android System back button, you can override that too. You don't have to create home button to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. I didn't create any back functionality.

Comment: @user6038386 But your problem was that app was not starting again. This solution solves that problem? What problem are you facing now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your MainActivity.java in onCreate class 



 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

After this in same file put method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id= item.getItemId();
        if (id==android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

please try this.

Comment: This code surely adds a back button at top but that back button doesn't take me to parent activity. Rather it just exits the app just like android back button is doing.

Comment: I wanted a back option which can take me to parent activity

Comment: okay. Just add in your manifest file
 android:parentActivityName=".Activitys.HomePage"

For Example:


<activity
            android:name=".Activitys.ChangePassword"
            android:label="@string/change_password"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activitys.HomePage" />

Answer (score 0):

this is same code working in my apps. 
try like this

```
public class ActorItemDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actor_item_details);

        //Back Button to go back

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id= item.getItemId();
        if (id==android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[this is my internal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFAqp.png)

---

[this my parent page ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6795.jpg) 
it's working properly